# springfox-swagger-ui webjar loading out of the box

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

I have just added springfox-swagger2 and springfox-swagger-ui to my maven based Spring MVC project and it all worked out of the box. I did not have to configure any extra resource handler for webjars.

Just out of curiosity, is such a handler configured by one of the springfox dependencies? Is there a way to track/log all the configured resource handlers in a Spring context?

Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot, a resource handler will automatically be registered for all webjars, so no additional configuration should be needed.  If you are not using Spring Boot, you will have to register a resource handler manually:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }

}
```